# Share Attribute Validation Annotation between different Models

Tags: spring, kotlin, validation, annotations

I have multiple Models with the same attribute, for example: CustomerNumber it hast to be always 10 digits long, it is now in the Model of Customer, CustomerContract, CustomerContactData, Entity and Restmodels.

I am looking for a possibility to define the Attribute validation only once.

I am using Springboot and Kotlin. ( Value Classes do not work because Spring ignores init and anotations of them on RestController  )

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please can you give us more information about your attempts? See the guidelines of [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to post great questions :) Take a look also to the StackOverflow [tour](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour).